# image() modifies actual image content in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am displaying an image in figure window in MATLAB using following code.

```
im = imread('Image02.tif');
processAndDisplayImage(im);
hImage = image(im);
set(hImage,'ButtonDownFcn',@clickInImage);
```

But problem is that the third line above makes the image changed for some reason I don't know. Is there any way to get image handle without the modification?

UPDATE: Resolved the problem. Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 hImage = image(im);
```

I used following to solve my problem.

```
 [hImage hfig ha] = imhandles(gcf);
```

But I still don't understand image command does to the actual image displayed on figure.

Answer (score 1):

The `image` graphical command cannot change the image. I can only guess that it shows the image in a way you don't want it. Inspect the range of the image -

```
  max(im(:));
```

and also the type:

```
  class(im);
```

and try to figure out what is wrong

Comment: Well, if the problem is that simple, I wouldn't have asked. im is usual unint8 matrix. image command removed grid lines I draw on the image and equalized it somehow. So image command actually does something.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could modify `processAndDisplayImage` so that it returns a handle to the displayed image as an output variable?

Comment: I can do that but how to get the handle inside of the function? Same image command? I tried it to have the same undesired result.

Comment: I'm guessing that since it's called `processAndDisplayImage`, somwhere inside that function is already some code that displays an image. Typically the commands that do this would be able to return a handle to the displayed image, or to the axis or figure that contains it. Perhaps this could be collected, and returned as an output from `processAndDisplayImage`. If the handle were to an axis or figure rather than the image itself, you could get a handle to the image by examining the children.